# has_and_belongs_to_many and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
class Trip
  has_many   :trip_places
  has_many   :places, through: :trip_places

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :places
end

class Place
  has_many :trip_places
  has_many :trips, through: :trip_places

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end

class TripPlace
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :place
end
```

So we got a trip which has many places through trip places, and accepts nested attributes for places. Also places must be unique by name.

I'd like to have the following functionality though, and can't find an elegant solution to it:

Let's say we create a trip `T`, with two places `P1 = 'hawaii'` and `P2 = 'costa rica'`

If I edit the trip, and change `hawaii` to `bora bora`, it will modify the `Place`.

The problem is that I'd like to create a new place called `bora bora` and modify the TripPlace model to update the `place_id` with the new one.

Same thing goes to destroy, if I destroy a `place` in the form, I'd like to remove only the reference from the `TripPlace`, and not the actual `Place`

And of course, the create functionality should be alike, if the place exists, just create the TripPlace reference.

Right now, I don't think that accepts_nested_attributes_for really helps, but can't think of a good solution for this

Comment: You can add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :trip_places` as well. And in the create view you can list all the places as check boxes as well as a field to add new place. In this way you can both create a new place and choose from existing. And in the same way you can edit/delete a place. I am quite busy right now otherwise I would have created sample code for you.

Comment: What you want to do is entirely possible, but you need to be more specific about how you want to do it. Please include some controller and view code. Or at least explain what you want the view to look like if you have no idea how to accomplish it.